# k3s: Worker node connects to master node but doesn't show up in api

Tags: kubernetes, devops, k3s

I have a 1 CPU 1GB VPS serving as a master node for K3s. (Is this too little?)

I installed k3s on the master node via `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`

I then copied the token from `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token` and installed on the worker node using `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=https://myserver:6443 K3S_TOKEN=mynodetoken sh -`

When I run the command on the worker node, the command runs without any output. It just ends. But when I do `k3s kubectl get nodes`, it only shows the master node, so it looks like the worker node did not actually connect. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Just FYI, the master and worker node are connected together via a VPN.

Comment: https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/installation-requirements/resource-profiling/

Comment: @tymur999 I am facing the same issue. Have you solved it by any chance?